# 3D Vectors linear algebra question

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm stuck and would appreciate help this question:

u = (2, -1, 1)
v = (-3, 6, 3)
find components of w so that u , v and w are linearly dependent,
(w - u)⊥ u and (w - v) ⊥ v

[visual of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdIaP.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when formatting questions, it makes it easier to read. Also, please see this guide on [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Users are happy to help if you show us your work and ask a specific question. What do you know about linearly dependent/independent vectors, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed to solve this problem

Comment: Did you try and set $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ and see what happens?

Comment: Sorry if this sound dumbs but I have no idea what to do after doing w=(w1,w2,w3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given $u=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix},v=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\6\\3\end{pmatrix}$, and let $w=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$. You have several conditions. The first is that they are linearly dependent, which can be expressed as for some a and b, $au+bv=w$ or $a\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}-3\\6\\3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$. You're also given that $w-u\perp u$ and $w-v\perp v$. Two vectors are perpendicular if their dot product is 0. You get $\begin{pmatrix}x-2\\y+1\\z-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}x+3\\y-6\\z-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-3\\6\\3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$. This gives us the equations

```
2(x-2)-(y+1)+(z-1)=0
-3(x+3)+6(y-6)+3(z-3)=0

Solve in terms of x.

y=x+4
z=10-x

From the linear dependent condition previously, 
2a-3b=x
-a+6b=x+4
a+3b=10-x

Solve for a, b, and x.
a=10/3, b=14/9, x=2

Get y and z.
y=6, z=8
```

So the solution is $w=(2,6,8)^T$.